# Create redirect with parameter in Laravel routes

Tags: laravel

I have this route in my `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/fr/action/{ticker}', 'AnalysisController@index')->name('analysis.slug.French');
```

I want to create a 301 redirect from this page to '/stock/{ticker}' but I'm not sure how to pass the `$ticker` parameter to the redirect here.

This doesn't work:

```
Route::get('/fr/action/{ticker}', function() { return redirect()->to('stock/{ticker}') });
```

Comment: Please provide the controller code. You can get the ticket as parameter and pass it to the redirect.

Comment: Can I do this directly in web.php without editing the controller? I can do the redirect in the controller no problem. I want to do it in the routes file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but this might work;

```
Route::get('/fr/action/{ticker}', function($ticker) {
    return redirect()->to('stock/'.$ticker);
});
```

But better solution from [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes), you can create a route and redirect named route with parameter.

---

EDIT:

```
Route::get('/fr/action/{ticker}', function($ticker) {
    return redirect()->route('yourDefinedStockRoute', ['ticker' => $ticker]);
});
```

yourDefinedStockRoute is the name of "stock/{ticker}" route

Comment: I'm happy to use the solution from the docs (return redirect()->route('profile', ['id' => 1]);) but my problem is - how do I pass the $id from my current route to the target route? They just hardcoded the number 1 in the docs.

Comment: you can do this same method up here on my answer. I am going to edit it. Look there

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Route::redirect` to do this:

```
Route::redirect('/fr/action/{ticker}', '/stock/{ticker}', 301);
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Routing - Redirect Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#redirect-routes) `Route::redirect`